# Advanced Custom Fields Repeater Fields Bootstrap tabs

Tags: wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, tabs, wordpress-theming, advanced-custom-fields

I'm trying to integrate Bootstrap Tabs with ACF.

But how should I pull data when I create more than one tab?

When I use a tab at this time I can pull in this way but when I use more than one, how should I do?

How do I create a loop to use multiple tabs?

How to pull Tab links and content?

Front-end Codes

```html
 <!-- tab start -->
 <div class="row mar0 tabrk">
  <ul class="tabnav nav-pills">
   <li class="active"><a data-toggle="pill" href="#home"><img class="img-responsive" src="logo.png"></a></li>
   <li><a data-toggle="pill" href="#menu1"><img class="img-responsive" src="logo.png"></a></li>
  </ul>
  <div class="tabbody tab-content">
   <div id="home" class="tab-pane fade in active">
    <ul>
     <li>
      <div class="media">
       <div class="media-left" style="border-color: #ecb319;">
        <a href="#">
         <img class="media-object" src="images/marka/1.png">
        </a>
       </div>
       <div class="media-body">
        <h4 class="media-heading" style="color: #ecb319;">Asset Management</h4>
        <p>Allow healthcare facilities to easily determine the exact location of tagged assets to reduce equipment shrinkage/hoarding, decrease the time staff spend searching for equipment, and automate PAR-level management.</p>
       </div>
      </div>
     </li>
     <li>
      <div class="media">
       <div class="media-left" style="border-color: #a8bbe1;">
        <a href="#">
         <img class="media-object" src="images/marka/2.png">
        </a>
       </div>
       <div class="media-body">
        <h4 class="media-heading" style="color: #a8bbe1;">Asset Management</h4>
        <p>Allow healthcare facilities to easily determine the exact location of tagged assets to reduce equipment shrinkage/hoarding, decrease the time staff spend searching for equipment, and automate PAR-level management.</p>
       </div>
      </div>
     </li>
     <li>
      <div class="media">
       <div class="media-left" style="border-color: #3dd0d9;">
        <a href="#">
         <img class="media-object" src="images/marka/3.png">
        </a>
       </div>
       <div class="media-body">
        <h4 class="media-heading" style="color: #3dd0d9;">Asset Management</h4>
        <p>Allow healthcare facilities to easily determine the exact location of tagged assets to reduce equipment shrinkage/hoarding, decrease the time staff spend searching for equipment, and automate PAR-level management.</p>
       </div>
      </div>
     </li>
     <li>
      <div class="media">
       <div class="media-left" style="border-color: #8a8065;">
        <a href="#">
         <img class="media-object" src="images/marka/4.png">
        </a>
       </div>
       <div class="media-body">
        <h4 class="media-heading" style="color: #8a8065;">Asset Management</h4>
        <p>Allow healthcare facilities to easily determine the exact location of tagged assets to reduce equipment shrinkage/hoarding, decrease the time staff spend searching for equipment, and automate PAR-level management.</p>
       </div>
      </div>
     </li>
     <li>
      <div class="media">
       <div class="media-left" style="border-color: #a4d46b;">
        <a href="#">
         <img class="media-object" src="images/marka/5.png">
        </a>
       </div>
       <div class="media-body">
        <h4 class="media-heading" style="color: #a4d46b;">Asset Management</h4>
        <p>Allow healthcare facilities to easily determine the exact location of tagged assets to reduce equipment shrinkage/hoarding, decrease the time staff spend searching for equipment, and automate PAR-level management.</p>
       </div>
      </div>
     </li>
     <li>
      <div class="media">
       <div class="media-left" style="border-color: #164f9c;">
        <a href="#">
         <img class="media-object" src="images/marka/6.png">
        </a>
       </div>
       <div class="media-body">
        <h4 class="media-heading" style="color: #164f9c;">Asset Management</h4>
        <p>Allow healthcare facilities to easily determine the exact location of tagged assets to reduce equipment shrinkage/hoarding, decrease the time staff spend searching for equipment, and automate PAR-level management.</p>
       </div>
      </div>
     </li>
     <li>
      <div class="media">
       <div class="media-left" style="border-color:#f0441c;">
        <a href="#">
         <img class="media-object" src="images/marka/7.png">
        </a>
       </div>
       <div class="media-body">
        <h4 class="media-heading" style="color: #f0441c;">Asset Management</h4>
        <p>Allow healthcare facilities to easily determine the exact location of tagged assets to reduce equipment shrinkage/hoarding, decrease the time staff spend searching for equipment, and automate PAR-level management.</p>
       </div>
      </div>
     </li>
     <li>
      <div class="media">
       <div class="media-left" style="border-color: #9c6cb2;">
        <a href="#">
         <img class="media-object" src="images/marka/8.png">
        </a>
       </div>
       <div class="media-body">
        <h4 class="media-heading" style="color: #9c6cb2;">Asset Management</h4>
        <p>Allow healthcare facilities to easily determine the exact location of tagged assets to reduce equipment shrinkage/hoarding, decrease the time staff spend searching for equipment, and automate PAR-level management.</p>
       </div>
      </div>
     </li>
     <li>
      <div class="media">
       <div class="media-left" style="border-color:#17dfc0; ">
        <a href="#">
         <img class="media-object" src="images/marka/9.png">
        </a>
       </div>
       <div class="media-body">
        <h4 class="media-heading" style="color: #17dfc0;">Asset Management</h4>
        <p>Allow healthcare facilities to easily determine the exact location of tagged assets to reduce equipment shrinkage/hoarding, decrease the time staff spend searching for equipment, and automate PAR-level management.</p>
       </div>
      </div>
     </li>
    </ul>
   </div>
   <div id="menu1" class="tab-pane fade">
    <h3>Menu 1</h3>
    <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
   </div>

  </div>
 </div>
 <!-- tab end -->
```

Now:

```html
 <div class="row mar0 tabrk">
  <ul class="tabnav nav-pills">
<?php $image = get_field('marka_logo');
 ?>
 <li class="active"><a data-toggle="pill" href="#home"><img class="img-responsive" src="<?php echo $image['url']; ?>"></a></li>
  </ul>
  <div class="tabbody tab-content">
   <div id="home" class="tab-pane fade in active">
    <ul>

     <?php

     // check if the repeater field has rows of data
     if( have_rows('marka_ozellikler') ):

       // loop through the rows of data
         while ( have_rows('marka_ozellikler') ) : the_row();
     ?>
     <li>
      <div class="media">
       <div class="media-left" style="border-color: <?php the_sub_field('marka_color'); ?>;">
        <a href="#">
         <img class="media-object" src="<?php the_sub_field('marka_sol_gorsel'); ?>">
        </a>
       </div>
       <div class="media-body">
        <h4 class="media-heading" style="color: <?php the_sub_field('marka_color'); ?>;"><?php the_sub_field('marka_baslik'); ?></h4>
        <p><?php the_sub_field('marka_aciklama'); ?></p>
       </div>
      </div>
     </li>
             <?php
         endwhile;
     else :
         // no rows found
     endif;
      ?>
    </ul>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

What I want:

[Image:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M0TOU.png)

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

So you will have to do two `while(have_rows('repeater')){}`. One for the tabs, one for the content.

**Example:**

```
<div class="tabs">
  <?php while(have_rows('repeater')) : the_row(); ?>
    <div class="tab"><?php the_sub_field('tab_name'); ?></div>
  <?php endwhile;?>
</div>

<div class="tabs-content">
  <?php while(have_rows('repeater')) : the_row(); ?>
    <div class="tab-content"><?php the_sub_field('tab_content'); ?></div>
  <?php endwhile; ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much.I will try :)